# AppDelegate.m for both FBSDK and LinkingManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

To use FBSDK I need this snippet in app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url 
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
    annotation:annotation
  ];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return handled;
}
```

To use LinkingManager I need this snippet in app delegate

```
#import "RCTLinkingManager.h"

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url
                      sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}
```

They're obviously duplicates. How do I combine the two so both libraries work?
I don't know any Objective-C

Comment: you can return different things by checking the sourceApplication parameter

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Of course, you can implement this method only once in your `AppDelegate`.

`[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate...` and `[RCTLinkingManager...` both return a `BOOL`.

You can put both snippets in the same method. I would suggest to return `YES`, if both `[RCTLinkingManager...` and `[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate...` return `YES`. Otherwise, return `NO`.

It could look like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url 
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

  BOOL handledFB = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
    annotation:annotation
  ];

  BOOL handledRCT = [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];

  return handledFB || handledRCT;
}
```

I can't guarantee, that you can use `FBSDKApplicationDelegate` and `RCTLinkingManager` in the same app, because I have never worked with this. But your code should at least compile.

Comment: Just ran into the same issue and this is still working as of React 16 and React Native 0.49.3

Answer (score 3):

Wow, exactly what I was looking for! The accepted answer works great, except for a slight variation, since my FBSDK implementation is different (newer?). Because it uses:
`options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {`

I just tried to use the same parameters as FBSDK, and it works!

```
    sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
    annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
```

Full method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  BOOL handledFB = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
    annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
  ];

  BOOL handledRCT = [RCTLinkingManager application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
    annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
  ];

  return handledFB || handledRCT;
}
```

RN 0.59.x

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using RNFirebase Linking:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
openURL:(NSURL *)url
options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
  
  BOOL handledFB = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance]
                    application:application
                    openURL:url
                    sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                    annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
  
  BOOL handledRCT = [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];

  if (!handledRCT) {
      handledRCT = [[RNFirebaseLinks instance] application:application openURL:url options:options];
  }

  return handledFB || handledRCT;
}
```