# react native how to implement deep link and fbsdk in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, deep-linking

I am trying to implement deep link with React Native on IOS using this link here https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e, however, I am having trouble at the steps of setting code in `AppDelegate.m`. As part of integrate FBsdk, my `AppDelegate.m` is having the following code

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
     openURL:(NSURL *)url
     sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {
         return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                    openURL:url
                                          sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                 annotation:annotation];
 }
```

then I integrate with App Deep Link (https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e), then it ask to modify the same function. Below are what Deep Link on IOS requirement for the above method

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
        sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:
        (id)annotation
 {
       return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
 }
```

So my question is how do I combine these two function

```
BOOL fbsdk = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                    openURL:url
                                          sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                 annotation:annotation];
BOOL deeplink = [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                                     openURL:url
                           sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                  annotation:annotation];
return fbsdk || deeplink;
```

Would this be a correct answer? or do I need to do something with the url that comeback from `NSString * scheme = (NSString*)url.scheme;`

Comment: For others finding this issue take a look at this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38945881/7172902).